# Printing on a pre printed stationery in java

Tags: java, printing

In my **web** based application, i have to print a report in a pre-printed stationary.

What are the options in **JAVA** which I can use to print. There are other requirements such as if the text does not fits one page, then the next page should be used for printing.

Also, some other queries that I have in mind are:

1. Will characters width play role? 'i' and 'w' for eg. takes
   different character width.
2. Will the print also depend on the printer
   which is being used?

**Also, I have web application, and the printing needs to be done on the client machine on client's printer.**

Comment: Much easier if you can use a fixed width font. Is that possible?

Comment: use monospaced font for this purpose

Comment: There is no constraint as such on the font to be used. But the report may contain English or Kannada language data or both at the same time.

Comment: Does Kannada language have fixed width fonts?

Comment: Why would a fixed width font help? Any kind of decent layout engine can wrap, fit and more or less automatically break words when setting text using a proportional font. It might however be difficult to find a programmable layout engine with support for Kannada at all.

Comment: Apache FOP supports Kannada.

Comment: Ignore Kannada for the time being, the question is, how do i print in the pre-printed stationary? I am sure there would be monospace unicode font available which I could use for Kannada language as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [XSL-FO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects) to create a layout template with absolutely positioned block-containers corresponding to each of the fields on your paper form. This would allow you to position the text exactly and limit the extent of the text block (using overflow="hidden").

You can then use [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) to generate a PDF file from your XSL-FO source file.

E.g. using this source file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" language="EN">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master page-width="21cm" page-height="29.7cm" master-name="A4">
            <fo:region-body margin-bottom="0mm" margin-top="0mm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
        <fo:flow reference-orientation="0" border-collapse="collapse" flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block-container position="absolute" top="3cm" left="3cm" height="2cm" width="5cm" overflow="hidden">
                <fo:block font-family="Times" font-size="14pt" color="red">
                    Absolute at top=3cm/left=3cm - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
                </fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
            <fo:block-container position="absolute" top="4cm" left="9cm" height="2cm" width="5cm" overflow="hidden">
                <fo:block font-family="Arial Unicode MS" font-size="14pt" color="blue">
                    Absolute at top=4cm/left=9cm - ನಾಮಪ್ರತ್ಯಯಗಳ ಮೋದಲನೇ ವರ್ಗ
                </fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

will produce the following [PDF file](http://jarnbjo.de/examples/kannada.pdf).

When printing the PDF file, you must make sure that the PDF viewer does not attempt to scale the output to fit the available printing space (I think this option is by default enabled in Adobe Acrobat Reader).

Comment: first, thanks a lot for the effort you have put in! I have dynamic content which needs to be printed. I know that I can use <xsl:value-of select="@value"/> and use an XML to print the value dynamically in pdf. However, I have requirement like the height of the cell should also not be exceeded and moved to next page if the case arises. How will i handle this using XSL-FO?

Comment: @Ankit: If my answer solves your original question, please upvote and/or accept it. If you have a new question, you should ask a new question and not post that as a comment here.

Comment: This was part of the original question. Please read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class [FontMetrics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html), and methods of this class help you to calculate width of a string in pixels.

Your application should know the printing resolution you are using, DPI, dots per inch.

So you can determine the printing width of your text in inches, via operation

```
textsizeinpixels/DPI
```

where DPI - is your printer resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use JODReports (free) or Docmosis (not free).  Since these tools are based on doc or odt documents as templates, you can use properties in your template such as "keep with next" and "allow row to break across pages" to make sure that when the document is produced, it moves onto the next page as you require.  Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.

I hope that helps.